# REGEX - Pattern for email and doesn't allow double dashes

Tags: regex, email, pattern-matching

I've the following email pattern:

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)
```

Now I have two questions:

1. Additionally I don't want to allow double dashes e.g.:

   > not allowed: john--doe@x--x.c--om
2. What do you think about the pattern, could it be simplified or does it have some mistakes or uncovered strings?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/201336/3832970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex: [`(?!.*?--)(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/lShEQC/6). I added a negative lookahead that will stop the match if followed by `.*--`, if it contains `--`

If you want to use this for a website then you should use another regex as suggested in a comment to match email adresses more strictly, or use available functions in language.